# How to create an empty XHTML compliant P node using HTML Agility Pack 1.4.0?

Tags: xhtml, element, html-agility-pack

However I try to create an HTMLNode for the P tag and inject it into the HTMLDocument DOM, it always appears as an unclosed tag.  For example.

```
// different ways I've tried creating the node:
var p = HtmlNode.CreateNode("<p />");
var p = HtmlNode.CreateNode("<p></p>");
var p = HtmlNode.CreateNode("<p>");
var p = HtmlTextNode.CreateNode("<p></p>");

// some other properties I've played with:
p.Name = "p";
p.InnerHtml = "";
```

They all end up as just `<p>` in the output after using the `.Save()` method.

I want it properly closed for XHTML like `<p />` or `<p></p>`. Either is fine.

**My workaround:** What I can do is issue `CreateNode("<p> </p>")` (with a space in between) and it retains the entire source, but I think there has to be a better way.

Other options tried or considered:

- When I turn on the option `.OutputAsXml`  it escapes the existing entities, for example `&nbsp;` turns to `&amp;nbsp;` which is not ideal, and it doesn't close my injected P tag.
- when I enable the option `.OptionWriteEmptyNodes` it still doesn't close my injected P tag.
- I see the Agility Pack contains the enum `HtmlElementFlag` with values `Closed, Empty, CData, CanOverlap` (Closed might be useful) but cannot see where I would apply it when creating a new element/node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer: the P tag has to be created off the `HtmlDocument` instance using the `CreateElement(..)` factory method like so:

```
var hdoc = new HtmlDocument(); // HTML doc instance
// ... stuff
HtmlNode p = hdoc.CreateElement("p");  // << will close itself for XHTML.
```

Then P  will close itself like `<p />`.

If you instead create an HtmlNode instance using the HtmlNode.CreateNode(..) factory method like I was trying in the question, it behaves differently in the DOM as far as closure.

Answer (score 0):

```
HtmlNode.ElementsFlags["p"] = HtmlElementFlag.Closed;
```

Default value for "p" is "Empty | Closed". You should to set it as "Closed" to return:

```
<p></p>
```